# Is it still possible to use the NASA Insights API for Mars weather?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, fetch-api

I want to you the NASA Insights API to retrieve data about Mars weather.

I have used their url: https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key=DEMO_KEY&feedtype=json&ver=1.0

and it just displays a JSON object with validity: false, and lacking all the data it normally would have. It's because it's only some time ranges it has captured data.

I looked at these graphs to see what sols have data:
https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/weather/

I then used this query to try to retrieve data for a specified sol:
https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key=DEMO_KEY&feedtype=json&ver=1.0&sol=1219

Is this the right way to query? I looked at the API documentation but couldn't see how I make queries for a specific sol. It's more about how to interpret the data as far as I understand, but maybe I'm not understanding it correctly. I use append `&sol=1219` because chatGPT did it and it makes sense but does not work. No matter the sol number it gives the same JSON with validity: false and no data.

How do I query it for a specific sol? And where should I find data on which sols have data, if not the site I already gave here?

docs:
API documentation: https://api.nasa.gov/assets/insight/InSight%20Weather%20API%20Documentation.pdf

All their API's, look under Insight: Mars Weather Service API: https://api.nasa.gov/